# uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS. I am getting this error when i am trying to upload an image to aws-s3 using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

## Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'tinymce-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.8'
gem 'haml'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.1.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'acts_as_votable'
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.35'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'puma'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

## Production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
end
```

## paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

## Details of Problem

*Problem is that when we use aws-sdk ~>2.0 Shows above error in the title while I am uploading image using paperclip for my heroku app. There is similar question but answer to that question is valid now as gem 'aws-sdk','~<2.0' is depracted now. It give corrupted gem error when tried to install. I am stuck in this for 2 days. Couldn't find any satisfactory answer from any resource. Thank you in advance  *

Comment: Which version of paperclip are you using? They only support aws-sdk v2 on version 5 (currently in beta) and greater.

Comment: gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'

Comment: Is there any prob with aws-sdk gem for version >2.0? Even at  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3 warning is given for usage of aws-sdk ~>2.

Comment: I don't think there are problems with it, just that Paperclip has taken a little while to update to using it. In order to upgrade to a compatible version, you could try one of the beta versions by putting `gem 'paperclip', '5.0.0.beta2'` in your gemfile and seeing if that works for you. You'll probably want to read their release notes to see what else has changed in Paperclip.

Comment: 'Paperclip::Errors::InfiniteInterpolationError' It is giving this error after upgradation.I would update my paperclip.rb in question.. @maxshelley

Comment: 'Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (getaddrinfo: No such host is known. ):'. I am getting this error after configuring to paperclip.rb with new paperclip 5.0 beta as above. @maxshelley

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822340/seahorseclientnetworkingerror-amazon-s3-file-upload-with-rails - If you need to get this shipped and you don't mind using the old version of aws-sdk, then downgrade your versions: `gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.6'` and `gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.66.0'`

Comment: `gem 'aws-sdk','~>1.66.0'`gives error saying corrupted gem!

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue. What error message are you seeing?

Comment: `Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/aws-sdk-v1-1.66.0.gem. It may be corrupted.` this is the error message! @maxshelley

Comment: Looks like an issue with your local Windows rails environment. Not sure i can help with that. If you Google around and investigate further (maybe a separate SO question?) then hopefully when you get those paperclip and aws-sdk versions installed they'll work.

Comment: I reinstalled my rails,now old version are installed.! But it is giving this error          `AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied)`