# Rails. Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

It's duplicating this thread [Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError Amazon S3 file upload with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822340/seahorseclientnetworkingerror-amazon-s3-file-upload-with-rails)
But I don't understand what's actually going on there. So I am looking for a better explanation here.

The issue - my app asks a user for a photo upload. Then saves the photo to AWS S3 using gem `aws-sdk-rails`. Everything works fine for the most of the times.

But yesterday I got an error notification:

`Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError: Connection reset by peer
...
99 File "/app/app/controllers/customers_controller.rb" line 22 in create
...`

Here it says it might be a network issue https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1572

But I still can't figure out how to handle this kind of situation.

Should I use some sort of background worker for this? I have no experience with background workers (if it's a right track at all).

Comment: Is your app server on AWS, too, or somewhere else? How often are you seeing this error? All the time, every few calls or just very sporadically? What zone is the bucket in and where is your application server located? It is indeed most likely that it's a network issue and these are notoriously hard to debug...

Comment: Thanks @ma_il My app is hosted on heroku. I saw this just once. AWS bucket zone is Virginia. I am not sure how to check where the heroku app server is located. `heroku regions --common` returns `eu  Europe         Common Runtime us  United States  Common Runtime`. If I can't debug this (most likely) what might be a workaround?